# Writing into database at 10 second intervals

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am using an emotion analysis API which analyzes a video and then stores the emotions read into the database. I have written the code below in an attempt to get it to store emotions ***only*** at every 10 seconds of the video. It wouldn't write anything into the database but however, when I remove the

> if (has.getFrameTimeStamp() % 10000 == 0) {

portion, it writes in as per normal every second which I don't want.

has.getFrameTimeStamp() = the particular second of the video

```
if (has.getFrameTimeStamp() % 10000 == 0) {
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"<file path>")) {
 conn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_VIDEO(TIMESTAMP,JOY_SCORE,SURPRISE_SCORE,ANGER_SCORE,FEAR_SCORE,SADNESS_SCORE,DISGUST_SCORE) VALUES('" + has.getFrameTimeStamp().ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.joy_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.surprise_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.anger_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.fear_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.sadness_score.ToString() + "','" + people.get(i).impression.emotion_response.disgust_score.ToString() + "')", conn)) {

using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader()) {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the format of `has.getFrameTimeStamp()` seconds, minutes, datetime, smileyfaces per hour?

Comment: @TheGeneral Seconds.

Comment: So you want it to update every 166.6667 minutes?

Comment: you should use parametized queries and not string concats.  If you want to make that easier, use something like dapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are basically saying is, update my database every 166 minutes

if you want 10 seconds, you need to do the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) of 10

```
if (has.getFrameTimeStamp() % 10 == 0)
```

Also

**Tip**, tidy your code up, you will trip over and hurt your self :)

---

[Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division
>   of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

[% Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

> The remainder operator (%) computes the remainder after dividing its
>   first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined
>   remainder operators.